# Request headers not passed when proxying with Apache HTTPD server

Tags: ajax, api, cross-domain

I have set up a proxy on Apache HTTP server for making the cross domain Ajax call. The call is happening but is returning a response indicating that the API key passed as a request header is invalid.

Can you make cross domain Ajax calls using Apache web server proxy? If so what am I doing wrong. ?

The proxy setting is as follows:

```
ProxyPass /api-temp/* http://api.temp.com/
```

The code to make the Ajax call is as follows:

```
var imageNamespace = {
    imageUrls: [ ],
    url: '/api-temp/v1/data/cat/42736286',

    test: function() {
        alert(234);
    },

    getImages: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: true,
            headers: {'API_KEY': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'},
            url: imageNamespace.url,
            success: function () {
                alert('success:', success);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('ERROR:', error);
            },
            complete: function () {
                alert('complete');
            }
        });
    },
}
```

Here is the response in the browser:

The URL it is invoking is as follows:  http://api.temp.com/v1/data/cat/42736286
Please enter valid API Key

I am passing the key in the request header but it is not being picked up. Any insight on how to resolve this will be helpful.